# Assigning a variable enum value

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following enum

```
public enum Outcome
{
   DontKnow = 0,
   Good = 1,
   Bad = 2,
   NotBad = 3
}
```

In my Results class, I have a property with this enum:

```
public class Result
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Outcome FinalOutcome { get; set; }
}
```

As I read data from the database -- using SqlDataReader -- how do I assign its value?

```
while(reader.Read())
{
   Id = Convert.IsDbNull(reader[0]) ? Convert.ToInt32(0) : Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
   Name = Convert.IsDbNull(reader[1]) ? string.Empty : reader[1].ToString();
   FinalOutcome = Convert.IsDbNull(reader[2]) ? WhatGoesHere? : WhatGoesHere?;
}
```

Comment: What is the column type in the database? Integer? You should just be able to cast the reader value to the enum type.

Comment: If the data type in the SQL table is a int, then you just cast it as an integer, then Enum.TryParse against it. I can give you a code example if you would like.

Comment: An example is the following, if the SQL data type is an integer : obj.OutCome = (OutCome) sqlIntValue;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(reader.Read())
{
   Id = Convert.IsDbNull(reader[0]) ? Convert.ToInt32(0) : Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
   Name = Convert.IsDbNull(reader[1]) ? string.Empty : reader[1].ToString();
   FinalOutcome = Convert.IsDbNull(reader[2]) ? FinalOutcome.DontKnow : (Outcome) Convert.ToInt32(reader[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your source column is a nullable int:

```
FinalOutcome = !Convert.IsDbNull(reader[2]) ?(OutCome)reader[2] : (OutCome)0;
```

Comment: Corrected, I just added a not :)